# Json object to varible to html with jquery

Tags: jquery, json, object, blogs

So i have this code and i dont get it to work, im working on a jquery based blog with JSON loaded objects and I have hit a wall. I need the objects properties into to a div element in my body to make blog-posts. I should be able to just put a new post in the JSON file and it should appear in the body. I have no clue on how to do this, my code looks like this so far:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

 $.ajax({
 dataType: "json",
 url: "posts.json",
 }).done(function(resp){

  for(var p in resp){
   if(resp.hasOwnProperty(p)) continue;
   var title = resp[p].title;
   var content = resp[p].content;
   var author = resp[p].author;
   var date = resp[p].date;
   var image = resp[p].image;


 }

});

});
```

and the JSON file:

```
        { 
         "post1" : {
                    "title":  "My day",
                    "content" :  "blalbvblblblblblblallksdlmalmdksdkasd",
                    "date" :  "12/0-16",
                    "author" :  "robert",
                    "image" :  "../blogg/img.jpg"
            },
         "post2" : {
                    "title":  "This right here",
                    "content" :  "blalbvblblblblblblallksdlmalmdksdkasd",
                    "date" :  "12/0-16",
                    "author" :  "robert",
                    "image" :  "../blogg/img.jpg"
            },
         "post4" : {
                    "title":  "Min vackra",
                    "content" :  "blalbvblblblblblblallksdlmalmdksdkasd",
                    "date" :  "12/0-16",
                    "author" :  "klara",
                    "image" :  "../blogg/img.jpg"
            }

        }
```

First of all the varibles i have created is undefined, why?

How do i make the varibles to contain diffrent posts?

Sorry that i suck on programming...

Comment: You need to change condition `if(resp.hasOwnProperty(p) == false)`

Comment: Why would that make a difference? And should that be === ?

Comment: how do you render the data in your html ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use object-keys pattern like this:

```
for (var key in object) {
    if (!object.hasOwnProperty(key))
        continue;
    var element = object[key];
    console.log(element);
}
```

You can add elements in dom use jquery [append](http://api.jquery.com/append/).

[example](https://jsfiddle.net/vtf2unyj/2/)